# Send an Email Using React.js + Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, express, reactjs

I have built a web app using React.js in ES6. I currently want to create a basic "Contact Us" page and want to send an email. I am new to React and just discovered that I cannot actually send an email using React itself. I'm following the tutorial with `nodemailer` and `express-mailer` but have had some difficulty integrating the example code with my React files. Specifically, calling `node expressFile.js` works, but I have no idea how to link this to my React front-end.

Nodemailer: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer

Express-mailer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mailer

My React component for the form is below. How would I write an Express file so that it is called from the `contactUs()` method in my React component? Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Col,
  Input,
  Button,
Jumbotron
} from 'react-bootstrap';

class ContactView extends React.Component{
  contactUs() {
    // TODO: Send the email here

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
    <Input type="email" ref="contact_email" placeholder="Your email address"/>
    <Input type="text" ref="contact_subject" placeholder="Subject"/>
    <Input type="textarea" ref="contact_content" placeholder="Content"/>
    <Button onClick={this.contactUs.bind(this)} bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Submit</Button>
  </div>
)
  }
};

export default ContactView;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the button is clicked, execute an ajax POST request to your express server, i.e "/contactus". /contactus can fetch the email, subject, and content out of the post data and send to the mail function.

In React:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/contactus',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // Success..
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
});
```

In express add the nodemailer code within an express post handler:

```
app.post('/contactus', function (req, res) {
    // node mailer code
});
```

Comment: Providing a more verbose answer with a code example will help OP

Comment: thanks for the advice, this sounds like it'll work! Also this might be a dumb question, but right now, when I compile my application, I just run ```npm start```. How would I get my express server to run at the same time?

Comment: You start the express server with node: node expressFile.js

Answer (score 7):

@ryan-jenkin is completely correct.

Alternatively, if you don't have / want jQuery as a dependency, you can use the native [fetch api](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html). Also, I typically set up my form so each input has a state, then use that state in the stringified blob.

Client-side (React):

```
handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault()

  fetch('/contactus', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.email,
      // then continue this with the other inputs, such as email body, etc.
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    if (responseJson.success) {
      this.setState({formSent: true})
    }
    else this.setState({formSent: false})
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

render(){
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
      <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} />
      // continue this with other inputs, like name etc
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Would using react-router complicate this process at all?  I have a react router in place, fetched from the client side, and have a post on my express server but am still getting a 404 that the route is not found. @blakeface