# Cross-Origin Request Blocked erroring out after adding application/json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I'm trying to send some data to Node using React. Here's my React code:

```
sendMail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // fetch('/https://uczsieapp-mailer.herokuapp.com/', {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var contactReason = document.getElementById('contactReason').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var additionalInfo = document.getElementById('additionalInfo').value;
    var body = {
        name: name,
        contactReason: contactReason,
        email: email,
        additionalInfo: additionalInfo,
    };
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
    console.log(body);
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        content: body,
    }).then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Here's my Node code:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var a = '=';
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('mailing');
        console.log(a);
        a += '=';
        var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
            auth: {
                user: 'someuser@gmail.com',
                pass: 'testgmail'
            }
        });
        console.log(req.body.content);
        let mailOptions = {
            from: `${req.body.name} ${req.body.email}`, // sender address
            to: 'alexander.ironside@mygeorgian.ca', // list of receivers
            subject: 'Email from UczSieApp contact form', // Subject line
            text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
            html: `
                    <h4>Imie: ${req.body.name}</h4>
                    <h4>Email: ${req.body.email}</h4>
                    <h4>Powod kontaktu: ${req.body.contactReason}</h4>
                    <p>Wiadomosc: ${req.body.additionalInfo}</p>
                    `
        };

        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }

            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        });
    }
);
```

So as you can see I'm using the [cors module](https://github.com/expressjs/cors), which is supposed to handle all the `cors` issues.

But that's not enough. When I get rid of the `headers` property passed to `fetch()`, the call is being done, but no data is being sent. When I add the `headers`, I get the fun

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

error again.

How can I get around it and what am I missing?

I used this answer when writing my code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965820/7055769

Comment: CORS is there for security reasons, taking into account that the cors code is (hopefully) not going to be deployed to production I think it is much better to take another approach, such as installing an nginx (or apache, or jetty or whatever other server that can reverse proxy your calls) locally and proxy your calls from the front server to the express one.

Comment: All I want is to send an email from the website. The database is based on Firebase, so Node will have no connection to the db.

Comment: CORS happens between the client (your react app) and the server (your express). You want to send the email from the server from what I see in your code so my suggestion still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there were numerous reasons this didn't work. I'm leaving this answer for the future developers to ease their pain.

This is the method that worked on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/',
    data: body,
    success: data=>{console.log(data)},
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

Here's my whole server side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

var a = '=';
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('mailing');
        console.log(a);
        a += '=';
        var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
            auth: {
                user: 'sqtableknights@gmail.com',
                pass: 'testgmail'
            }
        });
        console.log(req.body);
        let mailOptions = {
            from: `${req.body.name} ${req.body.email}`, // sender address
            to: 'alexander.ironside@mygeorgian.ca', // list of receivers
            subject: 'Email from UczSieApp contact form', // Subject line
            text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
            html: `
                        <h4>Imie: ${req.body.name}</h4>
                        <h4>Email: ${req.body.email}</h4>
                        <h4>Powod kontaktu: ${req.body.contactReason}</h4>
                        <p>Wiadomosc: ${req.body.additionalInfo}</p>
                        `
        };

        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }

            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        });
    }
);
module.exports = router;
```

So in my case I had to add these:

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

No idea why, but it just breaks without the `app.options('*', cors());` parameter. If someone knows a better answer to this, and/or sees any security flaws please leave a comment and let me know. Thank you everybody once more for all the help!

Comment: This just solved a problem I had been trying to solve for hours. Nothing else worked. Thank you for not being a DenverCoder9.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that CORS only allows some specific content types.

The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:

1. application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. multipart/form-data
3. text/plain

The origin parameter specifies a URI that may access the resource. The browser must enforce this. For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    content: body,
}).then(response => response.json()).then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: If there are only 3 types allowed, shouldn't I change the type of the `Content-Type`?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set on the response from the server, to let the browser know which domains can hit it.  Setting this on the request doesn't do anything.  Javascript cannot circumvent CORS.  If it could, it would be a pointless security mechanism.  This header must be set by the server on the response.

Comment: @Taplar But the server is not sending anything in response

Answer (score 1):

You mind trying this as follow, this should solve the problem :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //set headers to allow cross origin requestt
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```